# QGIS OpenGeo Explorer plugin fails when Publishing with "'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType' "

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite

I am trying the QGIS OpenGeo Explorer plugin tutorial at http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/explorer/tutorial/.

When I try "Publishing a QGIS project", with the quickstart project supplied for the tutorial, I get the error message:

> 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType' (details below)

If I try publishing my own QGIS project I get exactly the same error, so it seems not be a problem with the project itself.

I do wonder if it is a version issue, as when I earlier created a new catalog I got a message something like

> the specified catalog seems to be running an older or unidentified
>   version of Geoserver

But having searched for the issue, it seems that it can be a spurious message so I felt fairly safe continuing. It is a recent installation: QGIS 2.8.3-Wien, and OpenGeoSuite 4.8, on Windows 10.

Any ideas?

---

Details of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/PROGRA~2/BOUNDL~1/QGIS/qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\opengeo\gui\explorer.py", line 111, in run
    command(*params)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/BOUNDL~1/QGIS/qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\catalog.py", line 475, in publishLayer
    sld = self.publishStyle(layer, overwrite, name)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/BOUNDL~1/QGIS/qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\catalog.py", line 148, in publishStyle
    sld, icons = getGsCompatibleSld(layer)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/BOUNDL~1/QGIS/qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\sldadapter.py", line 199, in getGsCompatibleSld
    return adaptQgsToGs(sld, layer)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/BOUNDL~1/QGIS/qgis/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\opengeo\qgis\sldadapter.py", line 61, in adaptQgsToGs
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType'
```

Comment: I have done a fresh install (including deleting qgis2) and tried again. The error is exactly the same.

Comment: Please use Geoserver Explorer plugin instead of the old OpenGeo plugin.

Comment: I have tried the Geoserver Explorer plugin in both QGIS 2,8 and 2.14. I do not get the error reported above. I do not yet know GeoServer well enough but both my test map and quickstart examples seem to load OK.

Comment: The only issues I found on a cursory look were (1) the option to overwrite without asking worked OK on quickstart but not my own map; (2) my map had an error message 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type' (but still loaded OK)

>Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/...\geoserverexplorer\gui\explorer.py", line 98, in run     >command(*params)

Comment: Hi Peter, please file tiket  here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-geoserver-plugin/issues (if not already present)... with detail to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did anybody found solution to it?